# Javascript share sessionStorage among tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, session-storage

I am using Javascript with Chrome and I need to share the sessionStorage content among different tabs.

I know that i could use localStorage but I don't want to get the same storage when I open a new Chrome window.

So I need a mix between localStorage and sessionStorage to share the storage among different tabs of the same window, but not among different Chrome windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research on the internet and I don't think you can achieve what you want. This is because you don't have access to an instance ID or, for example the PID of an process in the browser. So your client doesn't know which browser you're currently in. You can only make tab cookies unique, not browser cookies.

Comment: How can I clear the cookies when I open a new Chrome windows without closing the open one?

Comment: Clearing cookies in both tabs or only on one?

Comment: Only in one window, the second one I open

Comment: I'm confused. You want to share data between opened tabs but not between opened chrome instances?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to share data only between opened tabs of the same chrome instance

Comment: I'm very sorry for the late reply. I seem to have misunderstood your question then. I am very sorry about that. I have updated my answer accordingly.